# jquery select with the child is not working

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
<div id="surname">
<span>Name</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the `Name`

#### My Jquery

```
 $('#copySurName').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $("surname span").html();
```

pleas see the `#surname span`

but I got empty results

Comment: you are not selecting the right element - `#surname span` should work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id selection (#) is missing in your Jquery code. Should be `$("#surname span").html()`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NXYuA/)

```
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#copySurName').zclip({
    path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: $("#surname span").html()
  });
});
```

Comment: @user3432257 make sure you are loading jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#copySurName').zclip({
       path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
       copy: $("#surname").find("span").html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alert($("#surname span").text());
```

Comment: it gives empty results too

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $('#copySurName').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $("#surname > span").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are Using `ID` as your `jquery` selector , please prefix `#`

You Can Try This

```
$("#surname span").html();
```

Or

```
$("div#surname span").html();
```